# QuickFix - parse string with microseconds to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, quickfix, quickfixn

I´m having the following error in my .Net application:

> 20170710-18:47:34.938 : Connection succeeded 20170710-18:47:34.940 :
>   Initiated logon request 20170710-18:47:35.012 : Verify failed: Could
>   not convert field: Could not convert string (20170710-18:47:34.979386)
>   to DateTime: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I want my application to support microseconds, currently I can send a `LogOn` msg but when I get the response, my App is not able to process the message. 
Actually, the received message doesn't appear in my Log nor does it trigger any of my events (`FromAdmin`, `FromApp`)

I've tried changing my Dictionary but I could not pull it off.

Comment: Question is not clear, plz see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: If you're parsing the string via `DateTime.Parse(string)` it will fail, since it's not one of the standard formats the method expects. Change it to `DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "yyyyMMdd - HH:mm:ss.ffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0):

This was probably caused by a limitation in [QuickFIXn](http://quickfixn.org/) which didn't used to support UTCTimeStamps with anything other than zero or three milliseconds.

This appears to have been fixed in [March](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/commit/de4700d198b1db31bbe0fc81fac82c5a4e481fd1#diff-cddde4051102109a6e1e557eab40c1fb).  (Though it still isn't quite inline with the [protocol](http://fixwiki.org/fixwiki/UTCTimestampDataType).)

You should be able to fix this by updating your version of QuickFIX.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in QuickFix/N version 1.8. You can [download it here](http://quickfixn.org/download/). Sadly isn't on NuGet yet.